# How to show default calendar in viewcontroller of iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, eventkit, mbcalendarkit

I am trying to fetch my default calendar view of iPhone  in my viewcontroller [image].

Does it Possible ?

Tab on button and open will worked([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"calshow://"]];
) and some Third party will also worked !!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Your question can be understood one of three ways:

1. If you're looking to *access the events* that your iPhone's calendar contains, you can use Apple's [EventKit framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit).
2. If you're looking to open the calendar app from your app, there's a URL scheme called `calshow://` which can do that. Based on my quick search, I'm unsure if Apple actually allows this.
3. If you're looking to display your own calendar UI in your app, there's a bunch of libraries out there.

<sup>Disclosure: I wrote [MBCalendarKit](https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can find it on Cocoapods on this link or you can get it on Github at this link. This little library is unlike the others in that its configurability is up to the developer.  You can check out some of the calendars that its users have developed for it here. And you can see its setup tutorial here. Video tutorials here. It also as a demo that you can download right from GitHub. Btw, If you have never heard of cocoapods, then invest 10 mins of your time to learn about it. It is the easiest way to integrate 3rd party libraries to your iOS projects.

Other top calendars I have compared it with:

- [CalendarView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CalendarView)
- [FSCalendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FSCalendar)
- [MBCalendarKit](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MBCalendarKit)
- [PTDSimpleCalendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/PDTSimpleCalendar)
- [GCCalendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GCCalendar)
- [CVCalendar](https://cocoapods.org/pods/CVCalendar)
- [GLCalendarView](https://cocoapods.org/pods/GLCalendarView)